# guava filter issue

Tags: java, guava

Can you please explain why my Filtering is not working? (the filter is not done and the message is not printed out).

```
@Override
protected void fetchValueObjectsListPostSpecificAction() {
    logger.info("~~~size:" + this.valueObjectsList.size());
    // show only scenarios which have applications related defined
    Collections2.filter(this.valueObjectsList, new Predicate<PlanScenarioVo>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(final PlanScenarioVo arg0) {
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!---FILTER");
            return (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(arg0.getApplication().getInternalId()));
        }
    });
    logger.info("~~~size POST:" + this.valueObjectsList.size());
}
```

At least I want to make sure that it gets into the apply method, but I do not see anything on output, only the size(6) and size POST(6).

```
~~~size:6 
~~~size POST:6
```

Do you see something wrong with this method?

Thanks,

Comment: What exact type is the collection you are passing as argument?
Are you sure it is not null?

Comment: Is not null, because before calling filter it prints out the size...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Collections2.filter` **returns** a filtered Collection, it does not modify the passed collections.

**EDIT**
As JB Nizmet explains below, `Collections2.filter` is a **view** over the original collection, you will see the `Predicate` evaluated only when you actually iterate over the result or access it.

It will be useful for you to assign the result to a variable, print its size, and look at the stack trace in the predicate method inside a debugger.

Comment: Good point. But what does it have to do with the lack of appriopriate log info?

Comment: The returned collection is not a copy of the first one with only the accepted elements. It's a view over the original one. Each method of the returned collection will use the predicate to compute its result. For example, iterating over the returned collection will invoke the predicate on each element to determine if the current element must be ignored or not.

Comment: Thanks Hemal. Seems that this was the issue:)

Comment: Incidentally, if you *do* want an in-place filter, you can use [Iterables.removeIf](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#removeIf%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29).  But usually a view is more convenient.

Comment: @ChrisPovirk : just in time your comment saved my life , Kudos!